# How does float computation actually work in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point

Please tell me how does c++ add two float type numbers and makes the process so fast. I am trying to create a library that can compute huge numbers but my process of adding them is coming out to be 1000 times less efficient than that to two floats.

Comment: can i at least know why everyone is down voting it as i could not find answer anywhere.

Comment: Modern CPUs perform floating point operations directly in hardware.

Comment: Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit

Comment: It will put the values in floating point registers and then invoke a CPU instruction to do the addition

Comment: Read more about [*What every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating Point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: For details about exactly how fast specific CPUs (like Intel Haswell) do FP math, see http://agner.org/optimize/, and/or other links at [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  For a simple example of how a floating point add compiles, see [compiler output on godbolt](http://goo.gl/MDmZ1J) for `float add_two(float a, float b) { return a+b; }`.  gcc.godbolt.org just runs `gcc -S` on your code, but has nice filters to tidy up the output for easy viewing.  There are existing extended-precision libraries, like http://www.mpfr.org/ and https://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the CPU has hardware that knows how to store floating point numbers and is able to directly perform calculations on them.

For example you can store two floating point numbers in registers xmm0 and xmm1 and add them together by getting the CPU to execute the instruction below :-

addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0

This is for a 64 bit "x86" but every CPU has similar.

Well, old CPUs such as an 8 bit Z80 had no hardware to perform floating point math and you had to write small bits of code to do so, and yes, they were slow...

Comment: Not every CPU has float hardware, but most of them probably do. Some emulate the hardware. But it is a little too much for a forum like this to explain how this is done.